# Reducer updating state for an array

Tags: reactjs, reducers

I am currently updating multiple item quantities and returning back an array of the updated data. I needed to update the current state with the updated values in my reducer. The example below in **UPDATE_QUANTITY** just returns a object and updates the current state. How would I change that if I had an array instead of an object to update the state.

Code:

```
const initialState = {
    listitem: []
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_ALLITEMS:
            return { ...state, listitem: action.payload.data.itemsList }
        case UPDATE_QUANTITY:  
            return { ...state,
                    listitem: state.listitem.map(
                    (content, i) => content.itemId === action.payload.data.itemId ? {...content, quantity_printed : action.payload.data.quantity_printed } : content) };
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to return an array ? reducer should return the new state so it should be an object

Comment: I am updating multiple records, so I needed to return an array with those updated values.

Comment: This array is part of the state object right? i mean its the listItem right ?

Comment: Yes thats correct

Comment: I dont see anything wrong here, i use the spread operator for state and list item you have used map which will make sure that the UI gets updated, can i know the problem here ?

Comment: The data coming back **action.payload** is an array, so I need to know how would I map that data to the current state **listItem**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218812/discussion-between-mig-08-and-guruparan-giritharan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion in the chat, you can iterate the incoming array and update the existing array based on that.

```
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_ALLITEMS':
      return { ...state, listitem: action.payload.data.itemsList };
    case 'UPDATE_QUANTITY': {
      const updatedArray = [...state.listItem];
      action.payload.data.forEach((element) => {
        const item = updatedArray.find((x) => x.itemId === element.itemId);
        item.quantity_printed = element.quantity_printed;
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        listitem: updatedArray,
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```